# How to move data from database in textfield using next button in java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

here is the code for next button

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
   {   

    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement ps=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    try{
         Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
         String srt="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/silicon";
         con=DriverManager.getConnection(srt,"rock","brock");
         ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from stu where id="+jTextField1.gettext(),
         ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
         ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
         rs=ps.executeQuery();


   if(rs.next()) {
        jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id")));
        jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("nam"));
        jTextField3.setText(rs.getString("qu"));
        jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("pr")));
        jTextField5.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("mob")));
        jTextField6.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("ad")));  
   }     
else
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new studentf(), " no record record to navigate in text       field");
   }

  con.close();
     }
   catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());</i>

    }

}
```

as you see the code i want such way of coding that whenever i click on next button i just move to next record i try most of options which is available every i searched all the topics here but none of them helps me to find my solution i just want on the click on next button the data on Text field changes to next record mean it shows next record i got a project over this i done add search delete first last only 2 buttons unable to do next and
previous button .please help

Comment: What is going wrong with your current code, are you receiving any exceptions?(If so, it would be useful to see your stack trace) What exactly is *not* happening? The more information we have the easier it will be to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a good few issues with this code, but I will talk about the most obvious. Excuse my ignorance if I am understanding it wrong, but if your current code executes each time the button is pressed then you are getting a fresh new `ResultSet` each time, and so each time you press the button your going to display the first result from the new results set.

You need to call `rs=ps.executeQuery();` outside of this method so that your not redefining the `rs` each time. That way calling `if(rs.next()){}` will move to the next result rather than navigating to the first result each time.

Make the following instance variables;

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
```

and add following into a constructor (or the like);

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
String srt = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/silicon";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(srt,"rock","brock");
ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from stu",
        ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

A word of warning, you will have to think of a way to close your connection by calling `con.close();`. You could call `con.close()` inside of your `@Override protected void finalize(){}` but there is no 100% guarantee that method will run when your objected is cleared up by the GC.

I hope this helps.

**Edit:** It seems as though you have a lot of questions about `JDBC` and `PreparedStatement`s. Here are links to the Oracle [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) tutorials if you need some further reading. A more comprehensive understanding of the subject might be in order.

Comment: actualyy i have one modication in it that is               ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));  so what happens if i add this query in that @rudi kershaw

Comment: `ps.setInt()` wouldn't do anything with the `preparedStatement` you currently have in the question. The `ps.setXXX` methods are there to define "?"s inside the [prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)'s query. But you don't have any.

Comment: i made changes in program in prepared stament query where i get my id from textfiedl so still i should follow ur solution @rudi kershaw actualy em new in jdbc